# level value in dynamic reconfigure

Tags: dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone, I am learning about creating a dynamic reconfigure server and I just do not understand what the level value is and how it is useful. Could you please briefly explain it and give a simple example?

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/210156/level-value-in-dynamic-reconfigure/) by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1305 on 2015-05-29

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2015-06-25**:
Nobody can tell just a bit about this? Thanks!

**Comment by [achmad_fathoni](https://answers.ros.org/users/32710/achmad_fathoni/) on 2018-07-24**:
Any update?

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2018-10-09**:
No update at all :(

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[This tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/dynamic_reconfigure/Tutorials/HowToWriteYourFirstCfgFile) provides a short description.  Another short discussion is [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/9883/what-are-the-semantics-of-reconfiguration-level-for-dynamic-reconfigure/).  To summarize, the `level` is just a bit mask that allows you to group reconfigurable parameters for your own use in the service callback.  For posterity, I found this tidbit (from the second link) useful for understanding:

> I had this discussion with Blaise
> Gassend a year or so ago. He said the
> `level` parameter is just a bit mask. It
> can be used to classify sets of
> parameters in any way that is
> convenient to the package defining the
> server. The bits for all parameter
> classes that have changed will be `OR`ed
> together for the service callback.
>
> One useful classification scheme is
> suggested by the `driver_base` states:
>
> 1. Parameters that can only be changed while the device is closed.
> 2. Parameters that can be changed while the device is not streaming.
> 3. Parameters that can be changed while the device is open and
>    streaming.
>
> But, servers are free to classify
> their parameters any way they like.

---

Originally posted by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) with karma: 1421 on 2018-11-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I did not find a satisfying answer in other threads.
So i am writing one here if somebody still requires it.

So the "level" parameter is a int variable, where each bit can be representing a reconfigurable parameter. For example if i have 3 parameters, level value can be set to "0,1,2" for  the 3 parameters in the cfg file.so the 0,1,2 bits of variable "level" will be set depending on what parameter has been changed in rqt reconfigure. If parameter1 has been changed, the corresponding bit in the "level" will be set to 1.

This variable "level" is passed in the reconfigure callback. So we know which variable is changed, and update accordingly, instead of updating all of them.
Hope this explains it. If any improvements to be made please comment.

---

Originally posted by [imranlivt](https://answers.ros.org/users/23702/imranlivt/) with karma: 46 on 2020-01-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2